# parsing json in jquery autocomplete

Tags: json, jquery-plugins

I've used [Simon Whatley's](http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/using-jquery-auto-complete-with-coldfusion) code for the autocomplete plugin. Now, I need help in parsing a jSON data. Here is my code:

```
    $("#country").autocomplete("data/country.cfm",{
        minChars:1,
        delay:0,
        autoFill:false,
        matchSubset:false,
        matchContains:1,
        cacheLength:10,
        selectOnly:1,
        dataType: 'json',
        extraParams: {
                format: 'json'
        },
        parse: function(data) {
            var parsed = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 parsed[parsed.length] = {
                data: data[i],
                value: data[i].NAME,
                result: data[i].NAME
                 };
            } 
            return parsed;
        },
        formatItem: function(item) {
            return item.NAME;
        }
   });
```

For example, I get this as my jSON string:

```
[{"name":"country1"},{"name":"country2"},{"name":"country3"}]
```

What I like to get as results, of course, are the values country1, country2, country3. However, what I get right now in the textbox when I type (e.g. I type "cou") is "undefined". If I click that, what shows in the textfield is the whole string [{"name":"country1"},{"name":"country2"},{"name":"country3"}].

I've also tried these but still not working:
[jquery autocomplete, how to parse a json request with url info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373257/jquery-autocomplete-how-to-parse-a-json-request-with-url-info)
[jquery autocomplete with json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592048/jquery-autocomplete-with-json-response)

Help please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use

```
var countries = JSON.parse(data);
```

Since you're using jQuery though, it's a bit safer to use [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) in case the browser doesn't have a native parser:

```
var countries = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: Hi Andrew! Thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion, but still it didn't work. This is what I get. When I type in the text field, I get "undefined" as search result. When I click that, the whole json string appears in the field.

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hi! I found out that Simon's autocomplete plugin expects results to be on individual lines and not in jSON format. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100047/problem-with-parsing-json-in-jquery-autocomplete Thanks!