# problem with parsing json in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having trouble in parsing my JSON data in jQuery autocomplete. My JSON comes from this code:

```
<cfset theQ = lcase(q)>

<cfquery datasource="#source#" name="qry" maxrows="20">
    select top 10 lastname
    from info
    where
    lower(lastname) like '#theQ#%'
    order by lastname
</cfquery>

<!---
Before we can serialize the query, we need to convert
it to an array of structs.
--->
<cfset rows = [] />

<!--- Loop over the query to convert it. --->
<cfloop query="qry">

<!--- Create a row struct. --->
<cfset row = {} />

<!--- Add each column to our struct. --->
<cfloop
index="column"
list="#qry.columnList#"
delimiters=",">

<cfset row[ column ] = qry[ column ][ qry.currentRow ] />

</cfloop>

<!--- Append the row struct to the row array. --->
<cfset arrayAppend( rows, row ) />

</cfloop>

<!---
Now that we have converted our query to an
array of structs, we can serialize it using the
serializeJSON() method.
--->
<cfset serializedQuery = serializeJSON( rows ) />
<cfoutput>#serializedQuery#</cfoutput>
```

I converted my query into array of structures and then serialized it to JSON. Now, parsing this JSON in jQuery autocomplete does not work. The data I get looks like this:

```
[{"lastname":"abc"},{"lastname":"def"},{"lastname":"ghi"}]
```

Here is the code for autocomplete:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#name").autocomplete("data/name.cfm",{
        minChars:1,
        delay:10,
        autoFill:false,
        matchSubset:false,
        matchContains:1,
        cacheLength:10,
        selectOnly:1,
        dataType: 'json',

        parse: function(data) {
            var parsed = [];
            var dataParsed = $.parseJSON(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < dataParsed.length; i++) {
                parsed[parsed.length] = {
                data: dataParsed[i],
                value: dataParsed[i].lastname,
                result: dataParsed[i].lastname
                };
            }

            return parsed;
        },
        formatItem: function(item) {
            return item;
        }

    });
```

When I type in the text field, I get the whole JSON string as the search result. I've looked into other codes for parsing but still I can't get it working. Any help? Thanks.

References:
Simon Whatley for autocomplete;
Ben Nadel for query to array of structs and serialize to json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that in your for loop you are iterating up to `data.length` when you should be iterating up to `dataParsed.length`

If you are using the Simon Whatley autocomplete plug-in, according to the demo on his website, the plugin simply expected the autocomplete results to be on individual lines, e.g:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

So you should get rid of the `parse` function you provide in jquery, and modify your coldfusion script to return one name per line i.e. `abc\ndef\n...` No need to use json or anything else. (at least thats how this demo on his website works http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/examples/autocomplete/jquery/data/country.php)

Just to confirm, you should add an `alert('aaa')` to the inside of your `parse()` function, I bet you will see that it is never being called.

Comment: @Jesse Cohen, sorry, that's just a typo error. Even if I've changed that to dataParsed.length, it still doesn't work. I just get the whole json, ie. [{"lastname":"abc"},{"lastname":"def"},{"lastname":"ghi"}] in the text field.

Comment: if you tell me which autocomplete plugin for jquery you are using it would help to debug this -- the different plugins expect data in different formats and have different configuration parameters.

Comment: @Jesse, for the jquery autocomplete plugin, I've downloaded it from Simon Whatley www.simonwhatley.co.uk/using-jquery-auto-complete-with-coldfusion

Comment: @Jesse, yeah you're right. The parse function is not called. So, is it okay to pass the results one name per line? Or should I get another plugin that accepts json? I'm a newbie in jquery so maybe you can give suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: As I said. Simply return 1 plaintext result per line. No json. And the plugin will work the way you want.